# Handling temporary errors

Tags: mysql

I have set up a cluster with 1 mngt, 2 data and 2 SQL nodes.
Each PC (of 2) has a data and an SQL node on it, the mngt is on a separate (3rd) PC.

I have written a Delphi application to try connect to a specific SQL node, if that fails, then to try the second node by using a `SELECT 1` query to test connectivity.
When I shutdown the PC with this first node, sometimes I get an error/warning message in my application saying something like "temporary server error ..."
or something like that. Unfortunately I can't always get the errors to happen.

Now I have put the ADOQuery.OPEN call in an exception block, but somehow it isn't catching these temporary errors.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: It might be a good idea to show the exact error instead of "something like that" ?